# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptacular, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to correct this issue?
I am getting this error while installing cryptacular.

ERROR:

```
PS C:\Users\gtaeh\Downloads\hindi-tamil-qna-master> pip install cryptacular
Collecting cryptacular
  Using cached cryptacular-1.6.2.tar.gz (75 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pbkdf2
  Using cached pbkdf2-1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\gtaeh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptacular) (63.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptacular
  Building wheel for cryptacular (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Building wheel for cryptacular failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-wheel-9782ix7m\\cryptacular-1.6.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl'
Failed to build cryptacular
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptacular, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have anaconda ,you have to install it through :

```
conda install cryptacular
```

Thankyou.